# Create progress line using VBA excel

Tags: excel, progress, vba

I try to create progress line by using VBA Excel command
I have all of data to define what progress is but 
I don't know how to use VBA for creating progress line

for an example I tried to use connector line but It's seem not work

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, 60, 405,800, 477).Select
Range("Z20").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Straight Connector 11671")).Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a shape for a progress bar, instead use the data bars conditional formatting on a cell where the cell value is updated by the code

Create a named range on one cell on the worksheet as, for example, "ProgressBar"

Adjust the width to suit your needs

Format the cell as a Percentage

Choose Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Format all cells based on their values

In the "Format Style" drop down, choose "Data Bar"

Select the "Show Bar Only" checkbox

In the "Type" drop downs, for Minimum and Maximum, choose "Number"

In the "Value" text boxes, enter 0 for Minimum, 1 for Maximum

Set the formatting as you wish

In the VB Editor, enter the code below

```
Sub UpdateProgressBar()
    Dim Rows As Integer
    Dim RowItem As Integer

    Rows = 1000
    For RowItem = 0 To Rows
        Sheet1.Range("ProgressBar").Value = RowItem / Rows
    Next RowItem
    MsgBox "Done!"
    Sheet1.Range("ProgressBar").Value = 0
End Sub
```

This will then update the value in the cell and the data bar will grow as the value increases.

You will need to adapt to your own code, but this should be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

some ways of doing a progress bar:

use the `application.statusbar`

or, use a userform, in wich you change the width property of any rectangle type (i use a button with nice picture font)

use a shape, from wich you change the size by altering its width property.

the hard part is more making it fast enough so it doesn't affect performance, and sometimes
when adding `application.screenupdating=false` in conjonction to `doevents`, it might blink... (or not)

if you need some code i can provide you a sample, and you can change it according to your needs